# Separate router and controller in koa

Tags: node.js, koa

I am using koa, and I want to separate the router settings and controller, but confused about "this".

```
let app = require('koa')();
let router = require('koa-router')();

class Controller {
    constructor () {
        this.users = ['ron', 'jack'];
    }

    getUsersFromDb() {
        return this.users;
    }

    * getUsers () {
        let users = this.getUsersFromDb(); // failed here, "this" is not the class instance
        this.body = users; // here "this" is the koa context;
    }
}

let controller = new Controller();

router.get('/users', controller.getUsers)

app
    .use(router.routes())
    .use(router.allowedMethods())
    .listen(3000);
```

Cheers,
Ron

Comment: I don't see the advantage of structuring the controller as a class. Koa will call the method handlers with its `this`, and so as you have found you won't have (easy) access to your own `this`. The controller is going to be a singleton anyway, so what's the difference between `this.users = ['ron', 'jack']` and and module-level definition `var users = ['ron', 'jack']` anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside koa middleware, `this` is reserved to koa context, and there's no other way how to access request and response. For that reason, you cannot use a class to define your controller, because `this` is already reserved for something else. However, you can take advantage of closures and use a factory function:

```js
let app = require('koa')();
let router = require('koa-router')();

var ControllerFactory = function(config){
    // config used instead of constructor parameters
    
    // Define properties and functions
    var users = ['ron', 'jack'];

    function getUsersFromDb() {
        return users;
    }

    function * getUsers () {
        let users = getUsersFromDb(); 
        this.body = users; 
    }
    // Export what you need
    return {
        getUsers: getUsers,
        users: users
    }
}

let controller = ControllerFactory({foo:'bar'});

router.get('/users', controller.getUsers)

app
    .use(router.routes())
    .use(router.allowedMethods())
    .listen(3000);
```

Comment: Yes, I did the similar way to achieve the separation.